# Remove focus from mat-slide-toggle

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-material

I have been testing angular material for awhile but i just ran into an issue with the slide toggle component and listening to keyboard events after clicking in the slide toggle component.

**HTML file**

```
<mat-slide-toggle color="accent" [checked]="likeChecked" (change)="selectedOpt('like')">
    Like
</mat-slide-toggle>
<mat-slide-toggle color="primary" [checked]="dislikeChecked" (change)="selectedOpt('dislike')">
    Dislike
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

**Component.ts file**

```
selectedOpt(option) {
    if(option === 'like'){
        this.positiveChecked = true;
        this.neutralChecked = false;
    } else {
        this.positiveChecked = false;
        this.neutralChecked = true;
    }
}
```

So whenever i click on the like or dislike slide toggle component. the component gets focused and it doesn't let the program listen to keyboard events until i click anywhere else in the program.

How can i unfocus or blur after clicking the slide toggle component programmatically? In order to listen for keyboard events

Comment: Please provide a stackblitz example

Comment: I added the dependency (angular2-hotkeys) that i use to listen for keyboard events such as the right arrow. Take a look at the console and it will show that is recording the logs, but once you click on the slide toggle or any of the other angular material components. they do not allow for any other events [Here is the example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jksdbh?embed=1&file=index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, hotkeys doesn't fire events when certain elements have focus. MatSlideToggle uses an input element internally, and that is one of the elements. But you can force hotkeys to fire for specific elements. This works in your StackBlitz:

```
this._hotkeysService.add(new Hotkey('right', (event: KeyboardEvent): boolean => {
  console.log('right arrow pressed');
  return false;
}, ['INPUT'], 'Move to next slide'));
```

(see [this](https://github.com/brtnshrdr/angular2-hotkeys/issues/86#issuecomment-401097097) for details - they have another workaround as well but that doesn't seem to work with the slide toggle)

The problem though, is that this affects all inputs (including the ones used internally by the radio buttons) so this might adversely affect other things depending on what key events you "take over".

I suspect that hotkeys isn't a great solution for use with Angular Material and maybe Angular @Components in general (at least ones that use native input, textarea, and select elements internally).

Comment: Yes, that is what i needed. Thank you, i didn't see that functionality and you are right, it might not be the best solution. Do you recommend another dependency for doing this?

Comment: or should i just go with the regular keyup event

Comment: I don't know the scope of what you are trying to implement, so I can't say if the regular keyup would be best. As for other similar packages - I don't know of any - sorry.

Comment: You could always use hotkeys and just add a key listener to specific things that don't respond by default - that might be a safe middle ground. If you refactor your listener functions so they can be shared then you could create a single listener 'master' function that just gets used wherever necessary and calls into the same 'key' functions you use with hotkeys.

Comment: Yup, that would be better using the keyup event for the specific component and calling the function for hotkeys as you mentioned. i didn't want to loose the functionality of moving inside an input or textarea. Thanks for the help